# Is it possible to reset SRAM in one cycle?

Tags: sram, asic

If you have some SRAM in an ASIC and you want to reset it to 0 quickly, rather than looping over the entire memory can you just write to all words in parallel by asserting all word lines at once (this would require a very slight modification to the address decoder)?

As far as I can tell, from a logical point of view this would be fine, but would it cause any physical design issues, e.g. current spikes; or any IP issues (I don't know how much of the SRAM is typically supplied as a black box)?

Comment: How much storage are you thinking of?

Comment: Say 1kB of 8 bit words.

Comment: I would think that connecting 1k memory cells all at once to each of the bit lines would probably overload the bit drivers, giving unreliable results.

Comment: That sounds plausible, thanks!